# VB.Net .Clear() or txtbox.Text = "" textbox clear methods

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, textbox

Not far into programming and just joined this forum of mighty company so this is a silly question, but what is the best way to clear textboxes in VB.Net and what is the difference between the two methods? I have also seen people be critical of folk using clear objects on their forms and I can see why but in this case, I am only learning.

```
txtbox1.Clear()
```

or

```
txtbox1.Text = ""
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two methods are 100% equivalent.

I’m not sure why Microsoft felt the need to include this extra `Clear` method but since it’s there, I recommend using it, as it clearly expresses its purpose.

Comment: Why only two? Let's go with a third one [Control.ResetText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resettext(v=vs.110).aspx) :-)

Answer (score 18):

The `Clear` method is defined as

```
    public void Clear() { 
        Text = null;
    }
```

The `Text` property's setter starts with

```
        set { 
            if (value == null) { 
                value = "";
            }
```

I assume this answers your question.

Comment: It looks like somebody at Microsoft had a bad day that day. This looks weird. +1 for digging it out. –1 for Microsoft for crappy documentation (“Clears all the content from the text box” – **really**?) and weird code.

Comment: Thanks very much. Very impressed with the speed of responses. Thanks again!

Comment: @Konrad: Well, it does.  What do you have against the documentation?

Comment: Hey guys! I can't accept and check an answer at the moment as, like i said, i am new to programming and still a little unsure about what is going on deep behind the scenes of the code you have all shown me other than clearing the text within the textbox on the form interface. I will defo be digging into my tutor for how these methods tie in with checking null references then i'll come back and rate an answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: @NeverHopeless: That's not sample code; it's the actual source code from the .Net framework, which is written in C#.

Comment: @SLaks from `sample` i mean the `piece of code`, I didn't say this a`psuedocode`. I know your code and code in question both are .Net framework's code. But it was supposed to be in VB.Net.

Answer (score 4):

Add this code in the Module :

```
Public Sub ClearTextBoxes(frm As Form) 

    For Each Control In frm.Controls
        If TypeOf Control Is TextBox Then
            Control.Text = ""     'Clear all text
        End If       
    Next Control

End Sub
```

Add this code in the Form window to Call the Sub routine:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Call ClearTextBoxes(Me)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Sub EmptyTxt(ByVal Frm As Form)
    Dim Ctl As Control
    For Each Ctl In Frm.Controls
        If TypeOf Ctl Is TextBox Then Ctl.Text = ""
        If TypeOf Ctl Is GroupBox Then
            Dim Ctl1 As Control
            For Each Ctl1 In Ctl.Controls
                If TypeOf Ctl1 Is TextBox Then
                    Ctl1.Text = ""
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

add this code in form and call this function

```
EmptyTxt(Me)
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear() set the Text property to nothing.  So txtbox1.Text = Nothing does the same thing as clear.  An empty string (also available through String.Empty) is not a null reference, but has no value of course.

Comment: The documentation isn’t definite on this so I wouldn’t rely on this behaviour remaining unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:`TextBox1.Clear()` It will work fine.

Comment: "...and what is the difference between the two methods?" -OP

Answer (score 1):

If u want to Selected text clear then using to this code i will make by my self ;)

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
    TextBox1.SelectedText = ""
End If
```

thats it

Answer (score 0):

Specifically if you want to clear your text box in VB.NET or VB 6.0, write this code:

`TextBox1.Items.Clear()`

If you are using VBA, then the use this code :

`TextBox1.Text = ""`
or
`TextBox1.Clear()`