# txtExample.Clear() vs. txtExample.Text = String.Empty

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When clearing input from users. What is the difference between clearing it in these two forms

```
txtExample.Clear()
```

versus

```
txtExample.Text = String.Empty
```

The only difference that I could find was that the labels aren't cleared with .Clear() (or at least from what I inferred from my book that's not possible)

Is there a noticable speed difference or should I just clear both labels and txt boxes with String.Empty

Comment: Find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754108/vb-net-clear-or-txtbox-text-textbox-clear-methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really is no difference, so it is a matter of preference to which method you want to use.  I personally use `txtExample.Text = String.Empty` for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Hardly no difference. Depends on your style or uniform of coding. Me myself pretty much prefer `txtExample.Clear()`